# Compute the maximum length assigned to each element using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

For example, this is the content in a file:

```
20,1,helloworld,alaaa
2,3,world,neww
1,223,ala,12341234
```

Desired output"

```
0-> 2
1-> 3
2-> 10
3-> 8
```

I want to find max-length assigned to each element.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you are blindly asking how to do a certain task without you showing any effort.

Answer (score 1):

Update:

1. OP's example suggests that they will be of equal lengths.
2. Using Spark-SQL and max(length()) on the DF columns is the idea that is being suggested in this answer.

You can do:

```
val xx = Seq(
             ("20","1","helloworld","alaaa"),
             ("2","3","world","neww"),
             ("1","223","ala","12341234")
            ).toDF("a", "b", "c", "d")

xx.registerTempTable("yy")

spark.sql("select max(length(a)), max(length(b)), max(length(c)), max(length(d)) from yy")
```

Comment: This won't work when all the tuples in the Seq don't have the same length. For eg. `scala> sc.parallelize(Seq((1,"One"),(2,"two","words"))).toDF`
Fails with java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: no Java class corresponding to Product with Serializable found

Comment: @SahilJ Two things:

1. OP's example suggests that they will be of equal lengths.
2. Using Spark-SQL and `max(length())` on the DF columns is what I am trying to suggest; The issue that you encountered is on how the RDD is converted to DF.

Comment: Fair enough. Could you modify the answer to include that assumption? In which case I can take off the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to extend this to **any number of columns**. First read the file as a dataframe:

```
val df = spark.read.csv("path")
```

Then create an SQL expression for each column and evaluate it with `expr`:

```
val cols = df.columns.map(c => s"max(length(cast($c as String)))").map(expr(_))
```

Select the new columns as an array and covert to `Map`:

```
df.select(array(cols:_*)).as[Seq[Int]].collect()
  .head
  .zipWithIndex.map(_.swap)
  .toMap
```

This should give you the desired `Map`.

```
Map(0 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 10, 3 -> 8)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using RDD's [aggregate](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD@aggregate[U](zeroValue:U)(seqOp:(U,T)=>U,combOp:(U,U)=>U)(implicitevidence$30:scala.reflect.ClassTag[U]):U) method:

```
val rdd = sc.textFile("/path/to/textfile").
  map(_.split(","))
// res1: Array[Array[String]] = Array(
//   Array(20, 1, helloworld, alaaa), Array(2, 3, world, neww), Array(1, 223, ala, 12341234)
// )

val seqOp = (m: Array[Int], r: Array[String]) =>
  (r zip m).map( t => Seq(t._1.length, t._2).max )

val combOp = (m1: Array[Int], m2: Array[Int]) =>
  (m1 zip m2).map( t => Seq(t._1, t._2).max )

val size = rdd.collect.head.size

rdd.
  aggregate( Array.fill[Int](size)(0) )( seqOp, combOp ).
  zipWithIndex.map(_.swap).
  toMap
// res2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(0 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 10, 3 -> 8)
```

Note that `aggregate` takes:

1. an array of 0's (of size equal to rdd's row size) as the initial value,
2. a function `seqOp` for calculating maximum string lengths within a partition, and,
3. another function `combOp` to combine results across partitions for the final maximum values.